# Different behaviours between platforms in react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a problem with the library [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view).

I have configured in Android `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and I'm using `enableOnAndroid` and with the same code I have different behaviours when I use a fixed element at the bottom, outside the `KeyboardAwareScrollView`.

The problem is that in iOS I have an extra padding with the same heigth that the outside component.

This is my test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView enableOnAndroid extraHeight={0}>
        <View style={{height: 600}}/>
        <TextInput 
        placeholder='hey' 
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          borderWidth: 1,
          height: 60
        }} />
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#f0f', paddingVertical: 20, width: '100%'}}>
      <Text>Hello, I'm bottom View</Text>
    </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this is the behaviour:

**iOS**

As you can see, height padding between TextInput and Keyboard is bigger than in Android and is exactly equal than bottom View height.

[image: iOS]

**Android**

[image: Android]

How can I do to solve this? Thanks in advance :)

Tested on:

iOS: 12.2

Android: API 28

RN: 0.59.10 and 0.60.5

RNKASV: 0.9.1

Answer (score 2):

Using `extraScrollHeight` in negative solved the problem.

Comment: Still getting the exact same behaviour as in your initial question. Changed AndroidManifest.xml (windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan") as well. I am using your code.